# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.uint8'>, <class 'NoneType'> - Keras Reinforcement Learning in AI Gym

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been trying to train an agent to play Atari games from the Open Ai Gym environment using the Deep Q Networks but I am running in to an error when trying to use the current state given by the open ai environment, which for this case is the Atari 'Breakout-ram-v0.

The issue occurs when trying to predict the q_value using the neural network given the state, and the specific line is

```
for index, (state, action, reward, next_state, terminal) in enumerate(batch):

        current_q_values = self.model.predict(state[0])
```

where the error given is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Documents\RL Project\Atari_DQN\atari_dqn_3.py", line 232, in <module>
    atari()

  File "C:\Users\Documents\RL Project\Atari_DQN\atari_dqn_3.py", line 211, in atari
    agent.train(terminal, step)

  File "C:\Users\Documents\RL Project\Atari_DQN\atari_dqn_3.py", line 135, in train
    current_q_values = self.model.predict(state[0])

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env_rl_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1013, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env_rl_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 498, in predict
    workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env_rl_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 426, in _model_iteration
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env_rl_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 636, in _process_inputs
    adapter_cls = data_adapter.select_data_adapter(x, y)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\env_rl_test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 998, in select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.uint8'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

I am really confused as to what the None Type object is that it is referring to.

The value of state[0] before I pass it to the model.predict is:

```
[ 63  63  63  63  63  63 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 192 192 192 192 192 192
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 240   0   0 255   0
   0 240   0   5   0   0   6   0  70 182 134 198  22  38  54  70  88   6
 146   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0 241   0 242   0 242  25 241   5 242
   0   0 255   0 228   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   8   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   5   0   0 186 214 117 246
 219 242]
```

Sorry if its hard to understand the code or the issue, I'm new to Stack Overflow and am a very novice coder so not too sure how to best explain it. Let me know if there is any further parts of my code that would be helpful to put on here. The model is just a sequential model of 2 dense layers each with 64 nodes (model not finalised yet so I might change it) and the input and output layers. The model appears to be created fine and I can see that it has the right input and output shape and structure from model.summary().

Thanks